# How to filter nested arrays of objects in graphql?

Tags: graphql

Here is my data in response:

```
    "contactInfo": [
      {
        "type": "phone",
        "data": "123456789"
      },
      {
        "type": null,
        "data": ""
      },
      {
        "type": "phone",
        "data": "1235553456"
      },
    ]
```

so when I filter it in query like this it works fine:

```
            contactInfo(type: null ) {
              type
              data
            }
```

it returns correct data:

```
"contactInfo": [
  {
    "type": null,
    "data": ""
  }
]
```

so how do I check for type NOT NULL? I want the query to return this array for contactInfo

```
"contactInfo": [
  {
    "type": "phone",
    "data": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "type": "phone",
    "data": "1235553456"
  },
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL does not define anythings related to such type of filtering requirement in the specification. So your question is purely an application specific problem which depends solely on that GraphQL API. The only thing you can do is to consult the documentation of that GraphQL API to see if it supports this kind of filtering.

Comment: This is the right answer. Simply do any logic required in JS on the result for the desired UI.